# Get Rectangle of Image JPG and generate thumbnail in rectangle

Tags: .net, image-processing, position, thumbnails

I try explain: I have a JPG image (img A).

This A.jpg has contents -colors, it's a picture of persons- and a one more little white rectangle (color white; the head of person is a white rectangle). I need get the position of rectangle in A.jpg.

Then, I have another B.jpg image, more little; and I'll generate thumbnail of B.jpg , with Rectangle dimensions (of white rectangle in A.jpg).

Finally, I'll generate new image: C.jpg, will has A.jpg, and B.jpg in rectangle of A.jpg.

any suggestions, any sample code ? I use vs 2008, .net 3.5, GDI+ only.

Comment: Basically you want to put a new face B to the person in image A

Answer (score 2):

For the A problem, you could count the number of white pixels in each column and each row. The columns/rows with the highest number of white pixels are where the borders of your rectangle are. (Assuming that the rectangle sides are parallel to the sides of the image)

For B and C the hint is to start with

```
Bitmap aImage; // Initialize with your images
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(aImage))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

And then you can find and overload of [Graphics.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx) to scale and draw your images atop of each other.

To count the number of pixels you can use the [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) method.

```
// Sketchy code
// Calculate each column in sum[x]
[x,y] = b.Size;
for(x ...)
    for(y ..)
        if (aImage.GetPixel(x, y) == Color.White)
            sum[x]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet on draing an image over another image. (No credit [i took it from here](http://www.windowsdevelop.com/windows-forms-general/embed-an-image-into-another-image-25895.shtml))

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(initialFileName);

// This draws another image as an overlay on top of bmp in memory.
// There are additional forms of DrawImage; there are ways to fully specify the
// source and destination rectangles. Here, we just draw the overlay at position (0,0).

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
   g.DrawImage(Bitmap.FromFile(overlayFileName), 0, 0);
}
bmp.Save(saveAsFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Now on how to locate a large white rectangle inside an image? This bit is a little trickier.

There is a [library which can do this for you](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/aa8125cc-45c5-6da7-0849-8665b609b6d6.htm)